# python menu, how to make this menu work

Tags: python, menu

```
def pickOne():
    print 'PROPERTIES OF SOLIDS OF REVOLUTION'
    print 'Pick a solid to analyze'
    print ' 1: ball\n' \
          ' 2: bwolingPin\n' \
          ' 3: ellipse\n ' \
          ' 4: tableLeg\n' \
          ' 5: quit\n\n '
    menu = []
    silhouette = ()
    flag = 1
    while flag:
        pickS = raw_input('What is the Number of your choice?')
        pickS = int(pickS)
        if pickS == 1:
            silhouette = str(ball)
            flag = 1
        if pickS == 2:
            silhouette = bowlingPin
            flag = 1
        if pickS == 3:
            silhouette = ellipse
            flag = 1
        if pickS == 4:
            silhouette = tableLeg
            flag = 1
        if pickS == 5:
            flag = 1
            main()
        else:
            flag = 0
            print 'Choice %s is not a valid choice' %(pickS)
            return
        tempinput = raw_input('enter min and max number of points to use (e.g., 2 1000)').split(' ')
        minNum = tempinput[0]; maxNum = tempinput[1]
    return silhouette , minNum, maxNum
```

i am new to programming,
i was been told to do a menu for a program, the body code i am done, just this menu really gives me hard time, hope you guys can help me.

I want this fnc work as, if user choose 1-4 for the 1st option, it continues and goes to second Determination that will return two int within 2 to 1000.
the whole function will return the name of the silhouette so that other fnc can call it. and two int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding of your question, your logic is flawed. First, you use `if` statements where you probably want to use `elif` which is short for `else if`. Second, your function will always end on printing out 'invalid choice', due to your flag setting. There's also an unused variable and a bunch of unnecessary flag setting, and your minnum and maxnum variables are strings instead of integers (a list comprehension can fix this). You can also do a thing called sequence unpacking to get the values from `tempinput`. Variable and function names are usually written like `lower_case_with_underscores` instead of `mixedCase`.

List comprehensions: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions
Sequence unpacking: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences

```
def pick_one():
    print '''PROPERTIES OF SOLIDS OF REVOLUTION
    Pick a solid to analyse:
    1: Ball
    2: Bowling Pin
    3: Ellipse
    4: Table Leg'''

    silhouette = None
    choice = int(raw_input('Enter the number for your choice: '))
    while choice not in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
        choice = int(raw_input('Enter the number for your choice: '))

    if choice == 1:
        silhouette = ball
    elif choice == 2:
        silhouette = bowling_pin
    elif choice == 3:
        silhouette = ellipse
    elif choice == 4:
        silhouette = table_leg

    tempinput = raw_input('Enter the minimum and maximum number of points to use (e.g. 2 1000) ').split()
    min_num, max_num = [int(n) for n in tempinput]

    return silhouette, min_num, max_num
```

Comment: You have no option for quit, and if you look at the comments in my answer you will see that OP clarified that `silhouette` should be a function. Other than that this seems like a more pythonic approach.

Comment: Quit from what? A loop that continually asks the user for a choice until they choose choice no. 5, and then return that last choice? No point having the loop at all...

Answer (score 1):

If i understand the question correctly i see a few issues with your code. You are using `if` when you want to use `elif` which is short for `else if`. The way you have it written the "Choice is not valid" option will run everytime unless you set `pickS == 5` Here is an updated code.

```
 def pickOne():
     print 'PROPERTIES OF SOLIDS OF REVOLUTION'
     print 'Pick a solid to analyze'
     print ' 1: ball\n' \
           ' 2: bwolingPin\n' \
           ' 3: ellipse\n' \
           ' 4: tableLeg\n' \
           ' 5: quit\n\n '
     menu = []
     silhouette = ()
     flag = 1
     while flag:
         pickS = raw_input('What is the Number of your choice? ')
         pickS = int(pickS)

         if pickS == 1:
             silhouette = ball
             flag = 1
         elif pickS == 2:
             silhouette = bowlingPin
             flag = 1
         elif pickS == 3:
             silhouette = ellipse
             flag = 1
         elif pickS == 4:
             silhouette = tableLeg
             flag = 1
         elif pickS == 5:
             flag = 1
             main()
         else:
             flag = 0
             print 'Choice %s is not a valid choice' %(pickS)
             return
         tempinput = raw_input('enter min and max number of points to use (e.g., 2 1000) ').split(' ')
         minNum = tempinput[0];
         maxNum = tempinput[1]
     return silhouette , minNum, maxNum
```

Comment: well, its not technically a string, because i was gonna call it like plotFnc(silhouette, min, max).... so ball, tableleg can fit the entry of silhouette...  @Victory

Comment: @user3505187 - ok i will edit my post, it was unclear from your example that `solhouette` functions were in the scope of `pickOne`

Comment: @user3505187 - not sure what is going on with `str(ball)`